# Unity UI - Assigning Event Callbacks Via Script Fails for Objects Instantied by script

Tags: unity, gui

So I have a pretty basic tower defense game going on, there are set build points each with their own mini canvas UI for building and upgrading towers. Once you build a tower on them, they disappear and I instantiate a tower prefab with the new UI setup for upgrading said tower. Now, if I have a tower pre placed in the scene all the calls to the UI button events (set up via script) work just fine, however for whatever reason on a cloned object although all the setup script is still being called (I checked with debug statements) the events will *not* be called. I'm almost certain this is a bug, I'm using the latest stable version of Unity (5.3.4f1), I have my canvas set up correctly and there is an EventSystem object in the scene. Here is the button event setup script I use (it's a component on the button itself which is a child of the popup obejct on the Canvas which is a child of the actual tower object.

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Events;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;
using System.Collections;

public class UpgradeButtonSetup : MonoBehaviour {
    public string buttonType = "";
    private AttackCollector ac;
    private Collector c;
    private UnityEvent eButtonDown;
    // Use this for initialization
    void Awake () {
        Debug.Log("Setting up");
        eButtonDown = new UnityEvent();
    //  eButtonUp = new UnityEvent();
        EventTrigger trigger = gameObject.GetComponent<EventTrigger>();
        EventTrigger.Entry entry = new EventTrigger.Entry();
        ac = transform.parent.parent.parent.GetComponent<AttackCollector>();

        if(ac == null){
            Debug.Log(transform.parent.parent.parent);
            c = transform.parent.parent.parent.GetComponent<Collector>();

            switch(buttonType){
                case "hp":
                    eButtonDown.AddListener(c.UpgradeHp);
                    break;
                case "resource":
                    eButtonDown.AddListener(c.UpgradeResourceGen);
                    break;
                default:
                    eButtonDown.AddListener(c.UpgradeHp);
                    break;
            }

        }
        else{
            switch(buttonType){
                case "hp":
                    eButtonDown.AddListener(ac.UpgradeHP);
                    break;
                case "attkspeed":
                    eButtonDown.AddListener(ac.UpgradeAttackSpeed);
                    break;
            }
        }

        entry.eventID = EventTriggerType.PointerDown;
        entry.callback.AddListener((eventData) => {ButtonDown();});
        trigger.triggers.Add(entry);

    }


    void ButtonDown(){
        eButtonDown.Invoke();
    }
}
```

Before I submit a bug to the Unity team I just want to sanity check to make sure it's not something on my end.